# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'c2' not found [The irony is that this column exists in the dataframe]

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function. The data consists of ten columns.

```
alpha
c1 c2  c3 c4....c10
1  0.4  a
2  0.3  b 
1  -1.2  c
```

I want to apply regression for five such columns. So, I tried to write a function.

```
function.one <- function(c) {
    glm(c1~c2,data=alpha) }

 function(c=c2)
```

I get the error such as

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'c2' not found
```

Could someone tell me why I get this error eventhough c2 is in the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `c2` is in your dataset, not the global environment. When you wrote `f(c2)`, R looks for `c2` defined in the global environment, and cannot find it. R does not know to dig around in the column names of your data.frame.

Supposing your data is a data.frame, you would need to reference it as `df$c2` or `df[["c2"]]` or `df[,"c2"]`.

You should probably read up on standard vs. non-standard evaluation in R, as it applies to writing such a function as you desire.